# Nextjs React Mui Autocomplete with React Hook Forms and freeSolo

Tags: javascript, next.js, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a Mui Autocomplete Component with a react-hook-form Controller.
When I set the freeSolo attribute the value doesn't get reset. When I call for example: `resetField("selBinvrk")` without freeSolo everything works as expected. Here is the code for my autocomplete and the submit function. Can anybody help me with that problem?

```
<Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={rules}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          disabled={!disabled ? false : true}
          value={value}
          freeSolo={freeSolo}
          //autoSelect={autoSelect}
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
          isOptionEqualToValue={isOptionEqualToValue}
          /* getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
              console.log('get option selected: ', option, value); 
              return value === undefined || value === "" || option.ID === value.ID}
             } */
          //console.log(item);
          onChange={(event, item) => {
            //console.log(item);
            onChange(item);
          }}
          //renderOption={renderOption}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={label}
              variant="outlined"
              error={isError}
              helperText={errorMessage}
              sx={sx}
              inputRef={inputRef}
            />
          )}
        />
      )}
    />

const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    console.log("hä: ", e);
    resetField("selBinvrk");
    resetField("selMenge");
    mutate({
      binv_id: data.selBinv.ID,
      bsa_id: data.selBinvrk?.BSA_ID || 0,
      binvrk_id: data.selBinvrk?.ID || 0,
      selMenge: data.selMenge,
      bsm_id: data.selBsm.ID,
    });
    //recaptchaRef.current.execute();
    //mutate(data);
  };
```

Comment: bit of a hack, but instead of using `freeSolo` can you just define your own `onBlur` and call `reset`? `onBlur={()=>reset("selBinvrk")}`. or ` `onBlur={()=>onChange("")}`....